# Basic references and advises for matrix eigenvalue/eigenvector problems having nonlinear entries $\bf A(\lambda)X=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, nonlinear-system

The following problem:
$$\bf A(\lambda)X=0$$
is called a nonlinear matrix eigenvalue problem where $\bf A(\lambda)$ is a square matrix with $\lambda$-dependent entries (nonlinear functions such as sine and exponential). The eigenvalues $\lambda$ and eigenvectors $\bf X$ are unknown. I am looking for a basic reference that explains efficient numerical methods to solve these problems.

**Emphasis:** The goal is to find as many eigenvalues as is needed one by one in ascending order.

Comment: I have recommended that the moderators migrate your question to scicomp.stackexchange.com. In the meantime, begin the process of narrowing the scope of your question if at all possible. Example, if you are mainly interested in a specific application, then provide some details.

Comment: I don't have an account at scicomp.stackexchange.com, should I create one?

Comment: I feel confident that this will happen if the migration goes through.

Comment: The suggestion to migrate your answer to scicomp.stackexchange.com was declined. If you crosspost, then remember to link the two questions.